# How to set frame for tile imageview in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I am developing an image puzzle app for iPad. I have succeeded to slice the image in different
parts and when I joined all images in tile view I am getting the frame of iPhone size and for HD images the whole screen will be occupied by the frame. So I want a fixed sized frame for all images in iPad. i am using following code to split images and putting them back together in tile view.

```
tileWidth = orgImage.size.width/NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES;
tileHeight = orgImage.size.height/NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES;

blankPosition = CGPointMake( NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES-1, NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES-1 );

for( int x=0; x<NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES; x++ )
{
    for( int y=0; y<NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES; y++ )
    {
        CGPoint orgPosition = CGPointMake(x,y);

        if( blankPosition.x == orgPosition.x && blankPosition.y == orgPosition.y )
        {
            continue;
        }

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tileWidth*x,tileHeight*y,tileWidth,tileHeight);
        CGImageRef tileImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( orgImage.CGImage,frame );
        UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tileImageRef];

        CGRect tileFrame =  CGRectMake((tileWidth+TILE_SPACING)*x,(tileHeight+TILE_SPACING)*y,tileWidth,tileHeight );

        tileImageView = [[Tile alloc] initWithImage:tileImage];
        tileImageView.frame = tileFrame;
        tileImageView.originalPosition = orgPosition;
        tileImageView.currentPosition = orgPosition;
        CGImageRelease( tileImageRef );
        [tiles addObject:tileImageView];
        [tileImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        // now add to view
        //[self.view insertSubview:tileImageView atIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:tileImageView];
    }
}
[self shuffle];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem - you didn't state a clear question.  Is it that your HD images use larger frame sizes?  If so, thought of using UIView's resize mode?

Comment: by using above code I am getting the tile image view in iPhone size but i need it according to my dimensions. and size occupied by HD images is the complete frame of iPad. but i want same frame for all images no matter how big an image is. If I try to set the frame using [tileImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(200,250,300,300)]; ,it is not working. plz give some advice

Comment: Seems you need to control/understand better how to set/init orgImage